# Return -1 and 1 when implement Comparable<T> in java

Tags: java

```
class Employee implements Comparable<Employee> {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;

    Employee(int id, String name, int age) {
        this.id = id;
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    public int compareTo(Employee employee) {
        /*if (age == employee.age)
            return 0;
        else if (age > employee.age)
            return 1;
        else
            return -1;*/
        return -1;
    }
}



public class TestSorting {
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList<Employee> al = new ArrayList<Employee>();
        al.add(new Employee(101, "Peter", 23));
        al.add(new Employee(106, "Marry", 29));
        al.add(new Employee(105, "John", 21));
        //Before sorting
        for (Employee st : al) {
            System.out.println(st.id + " " + st.name + " " + st.age);
        }
        System.out.println("================");
        //After sorting
        Collections.sort(al);
        for (Employee st : al) {
            System.out.println(st.id + " " + st.name + " " + st.age);
        }
    }
}
```

At the first time, I override the method `compareTo`:

```
if (age == employee.age)
    return 0;
else if (age > employee.age)
    return 1;
else
    return -1;
```

The result is that:

```
101 Peter 23
106 Marry 29
105 John 21
================
105 John 21
101 Peter 23
106 Marry 29
```

The second time I override this method with nothing in the body except `return -1` . I expected the result after sorting should be the same as the original, but the result is conversely. And when I `return 1` in the method `conpareTo`, the result is the same as the original, which is not what I expected. That is the result if I `return -1` in the `compareTo` method:

```
101 Peter 23
106 Marry 29
105 John 21
================
105 John 21
106 Marry 29
101 Peter 23
```

**New update:**

The reason for me to think when `return -1`, there should be nothing happen is that. According to algorithm of sorting, when sorting an array, we can do that:
we can use this algorithm:

```
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int[] arr = { 6, 9, 3, 5, 7, 1, 8 };
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));
        for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
            for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
                if (arr[i] > arr[j]) {
                    int temp = arr[i];
                    arr[i] = arr[j];
                    arr[j] = temp;
                }
            }
        }
        System.out.println(Arrays.toString(arr));

    }
}
```

I thought the algorithm of Comparable is something looking like this algorithm. So when `return -1` in the method, then `this age` is always less than `that age`; so there are no swapping (it is like  `arr[i] > arr[j]` is always `false`, and there is no swapping). And when `return 1`, it means that `this age` is always greater than `that age`, so there is swapping (it is like  `arr[i] > arr[j]` is always `true`, and there is swapping) and the result is the array with reversing order, compared to the orignal. 
if we change the code to:

```
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length - 1; i++) {
        for (int j = i; j < arr.length; j++) {
            if (true) {
                int temp = arr[i];
                arr[i] = arr[j];
                arr[j] = temp;
            }
        }
    }
```

we get the result:

```
[6, 9, 3, 5, 7, 1, 8]
[8, 1, 7, 5, 3, 9, 6]
```

That is why I think when `return 1` in the method `compareTo`. we shoule make the original list into the list with reversing order. But the truth is not. We just get that result when `return -1`

Comment: If you just want to compare a single integer field just do `return Integer.compare(this.age, employee.age)`

Comment: When you return `-1` you telling to `sort` method that each `Employee` is less then any `Employee` which doesn't make sense. What result you want to achieve?

Comment: "I expected the result after sorting should be the same as the original, but the result is conversely." Why did you expect another result? Please explain.

Comment: @Michael. Yes, we can do that. but I don't know why when `return 1`, there is nothing happen.

Comment: @talex. when I return -1, I think it shoule be there is nothing happen. but what we get is the converse order according to the age.

Comment: @Javing `compareTo` is not about "happening" it define relation between objects. `-1` mean object is smaller then argument. You can read mor in JavaDock.

Comment: @Seelenvirtuose. I have new update for you question. I thank you so much.

Answer (score 6):

> The second time I override this method with nothing in the body except
>   `return -1` ...

By doing so you are violating the contract of `Comparable`, which is [defined in the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Comparable.html#compareTo-T-). You're saying that everything is less than everything else, which cannot possibly be true.

`A < B` and `B < A` is a paradox.

Thus, expecting the order to be unchanged is the wrong expectation. When you violate the contract of `Comparable`, the sorting behaviour is undefined. There are no results which are more or less correct than any others.

Comment: I thank you so much.
May you or anyone else explain to me why there is nothing happen when I `return 1`.

Comment: @Javing You are still violating the contract but in the opposite way. When you do that, everything is larger than everything else, which also cannot be true. Again, the sorting behaviour is undefined. The fact that the order doesn't change should be considered nothing more than a random coincidence (in practice, nothing here is actually *random*, but still)

Comment: Your reasoning is not sound. **Always** returning anything is **always** wrong. "it mean that this age is always greater then that age, so there are swapping" Not all sorting algorithms even use swaps. See, for example, [insertion sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insertion_sort).

Comment: "Always returning anything is always wrong" - with the exception that you can always return 0 and fulfill `Comparable `s contact, but you won't establish any order with it.

Answer (score 2):

@Michael's answer is correct, let me add a side note.

`Comparable<T>` is intended for the "natural order"; I'm not sure that age is the most relevant order you can sort persons by.

What you may want is rather

```
class Employee {
    int id;
    String name;
    int age;

    static public final Comparator<Employee> AGE_COMPARATOR =
        Comparator.comparing(Employee::getAge);

    static public final Comparator<Employee> NAME_COMPARATOR =
        Comparator.comparing(Employee::getName);

    static public final Comparator<Employee> SALARY_COMPARATOR =
        Comparator.comparing(Employee::getSalary);
}
```

Now you can sort your `Employee`s by any of its attributes, eg

```
Collections.sort(employeeList, Employee.AGE_COMPARATOR);
```

Comment: Yeah, I agree. I actually find myself very rarely implementing `Comparable`. Natural ordering doesn't lend itself to many situations.